# Set a BasicEditField Filter on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to make a [BasicEditField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/BasicEditField.html) that should accept only uppercase letters, lowercase letters and numeric values. It should not accept any other symbol. Is there any style bit available for BlackBerry [BasicEditField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/BasicEditField.html) that makes it work this way?  If not, is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 6):

I use these methods: [TextFilter#get](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/text/TextFilter.html#get(int)) and [BasicEditField#setFilter](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/BasicEditField.html#setFilter(net.rim.device.api.ui.text.TextFilter))

```
mEdit = new EditField();
mEdit.setFilter(TextFilter.get(TextFilter.NUMERIC));
```

or

```
// Numeric filter that also allows minus sign. 
mEdit.setFilter(TextFilter.get(TextFilter.INTEGER));
```

I think creating your own filter by overriding TextFilter can solve more difficult filtering task.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it is not possible to combine them like that then, I didn't try it.  Whenever I have used filters in my code I have always done it the second way I mentioned above.  It is a bit more complicated but gives you a lot more control over what the field can and cannot accept.  Check out the API documentation on the TextFilter class.  As I said above you would just have to implement the convert and validate methods.  I think in your case you wouldn't have to do anything in convert.  But in the validate method you would just have to check that the character is in the range a-z A-Z or 0-9.  If it is return true, otherwise return false.  This will stop all unwanted characters from appearing in the field.

Answer (score 3):

With a BasicEditField this is not easily implementable; however, the right solution would change the BasicEditField with AutoTextEditField. When creating the AutoTextEditField, use the constructor where you can pass in parameters. This should do it for you.

```
new AutoTextEditField("My label:", "initial value", 1024, 50,
                      TextFilter.LOWERCASE | TextFilter.NUMERIC);
```

Comment: -1: This information about AutoTextEditField is irrelevant to the original question about BasicEditField.

Comment: It is easily understandable, that with BasicEditField this is not easily (if at all) implementable; however, the right solution would change the BasicEditField with AutoTextEditField.
Hence, the different field used.

Comment: Well, I can't change the voting unless you edit your answer - SO rule.

Comment: Please read the question posted again. it ends with, I quote:
"If not, is there anything else I can do?"
Hence, both of your comments are irrelevant, if not even rude.

Comment: You realize you are responding to a downvote and comment from 2012? I offered to change the vote if you edit your question.  That's due to the 2012 part, and the way SO works.

Comment: For example, you could edit your answer to explicitly say what you mentioned in your March 4th comment.

Comment: For more information on locked votes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited

Comment: I just realized you might not be able to edit your answers yet, so I made the edit, which lets me change my vote.  All fixed.

Answer (score 1):

mEdit.setFilter(TextFilter.get(TextFilter.NUMERIC)); works fine, also, I think, it doesnt take the minus sign, as while testing 'm not able to insert "-" minus sign in the field.

Answer (score 0):

There is a constructor that allows you to specify the style of the field.  You can then OR together the styles you want, like FILTER_UPPERCASE | FILTER_LOWERCASE | FILTER_NUMERIC.

Alternatively you can call setFilter and create your own subclass of TextFilter, which allows you to specify the exact behaviour you want by overwriting the convert and validate methods.  Convert allows you to force certain things like automatically make all text entered uppercase etc.  Validate allows you to block certain things from being entered, e.g. special characters.  Check out the API for more information.

Comment: Hi Dave i tried "FILTER_UPPERCASE | FILTER_LOWERCASE | FILTER_NUMERIC" this one, but i consider the first filter only ex.in the above style ur given uppercase,lowercase and numeric.But the filter is accepting only uppercase only.

Answer (score -1):

Kumar I also faced the same issue, used the below code to fix it -

The below script will allow Uppercase, Lowercase, Numeric values only.

```
setFilter(new TextFilter() {
        public boolean validate(char c) {
            return (Character.isDigit(c) || Character.isLowerCase(c) || Character.isUpperCase(c));
        }
        public char convert(char c, int status) {
            return c;
        }}
```

Comment: setFilter would not be appropriate at this place.